# Prepositions used with 'common'

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Is the sentence, "There is nothing common between you and me." wrong grammatically? If yes, why?
Should it be, "There is nothing **in** common between you and me."?

Comment: Usually we say "we **have** nothing in common."

Comment: Yes, or - *there is nothing in common between us*.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatical, but they can mean different things.

Which you *should* say depends entirely on what you're trying to express.

---

> 1. There is nothing ***common*** between you and me.

This could be interpreted to mean *there is nothing [that is considered] **ordinary** [located] between you and me*. For instance, what's between us on the table is not an everyday hamburger but a rare and expensive five-course meal.

---

> 2. There is nothing ***in common*** between you and me.

This means that the two of us don't *share* anything that is the same. For instance, we will never agree on anything because we don't share any of the same opinions.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of *common*, there is an entry for the phrase [*in common*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/common#h2) specifically:

> **in common**
>   : shared together
>   // has a lot *in common* with his neighbors

---

The first *could* be interpreted to mean the second, but if you're talking about sharing something, it's more likely to be understood if you add the preposition *in* to the sentence.